# Keras prediction incorrect with scaler and feature selection

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn

I build an application that trains a Keras binary classifier model (0 or 1) every x time (hourly,daily) given the new data. The data preparation, training and testing works well, or at least as expected. It tests different features and scales it with MinMaxScaler (some values are negative).

On live data predictions with one single data point, the values are unrealistic (around 0.9987 to 1 most of the time, which is inaccurate). Since the result should be how close to "1" the prediction is, getting such high numbers constantly raises alerts.

**Code for live prediction is as follows**

current_df is a pandas dataframe that contains the 1 row with the data pulled live and the column headers, we select the "features" (since why load the features from the db and we implement dynamic feature selection when training the model, which could mean on every model there are different features)

Get the features as a list:

```
# Convert literal str to list
features = ast.literal_eval(features)
```

Then select only the features that I need in the dataframe:

```
# Select the features
selected_df = current_df[features]
```

Get the values as a list:

```
 # Get the values of the df
 current_list = selected_df.values.tolist()[0]
```

Then I reshape it:

```
 # Reshape to allow scaling and predicting
 current_list = np.reshape(current_list, (-1, 1))
```

If I call "transform" instead of "fit_transform" in the line above, I get the following error: **This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.**

Reshape again:

```
# Reshape to be able to scale
current_list = np.reshape(current_list, (1, -1))
```

Loads the model using Keras (model_location is a Path) and predict:

```
# Loads the model from the local folder
reconstructed_model = keras.models.load_model(model_location)

prediction = reconstructed_model.predict(current_list)
prediction = prediction.flat[0]
```

**Updated**

The data gets scaled using fit_transform and transform (MinMaxScaler although it can be Standard Scaler):

```
X_train = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(X_train), columns=X_train.columns, index=X_train.index)
X_test = pd.DataFrame(scaler.transform(X_test), columns=X_test.columns, index=X_test.index)
```

And this is run when training the model (the "model" config is not shown):

```
# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
                loss=loss, 
                metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

# build the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epochs, verbose=0)

# Evaluate using Keras built-in function
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
testing_accuracy = scores[1]

# create model with sklearn KerasClassifier for evaluation
eval_model = KerasClassifier(model=model, epochs=epochs, batch_size=10, verbose=0)

# Evaluate model using RepeatedStratifiedKFold
accuracy = ML.evaluate_model_KFold(eval_model, X_test, y_test)

# Predict testing data
pred_test= model.predict(X_test, verbose=0)
pred_test = pred_test.flatten()

# extract the predicted class labels
y_predicted_test = np.where(pred_test > 0.5, 1, 0)
```

Regarding feature selection, the features are not always the same --I use both SelectKBest (10 or 15 features) or RFECV. And select the trained model with highest accuracy, meaning the features can be different.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? I'm thinking maybe the scaling should be done before the feature selection or there's some issue with the scaling (since maybe some values might be 0 when training and 100 when using it and the features are not necessarily the same when scaling).

Comment: How are you scaling your features? I see a `fit_transform` listed, but not a `transform` step showing what happens at prediction time.

Comment: I am using "fit_transform" as you see in the code

Comment: `fit_transform` should only be used during training, since it sets parameters. At test time, you should use the same instance and apply `scaler.transform(X_test)` for any new data.

Comment: Just did that and got This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

Comment: I've added an answer. It sounds like the scaler is missing a step, or that there are separate scripts handling learning and prediction. Happy to clarify if something doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues seems to stem from a `StandardScaler` / `MinMaxScaler`. The following example shows how to apply the former. However, if there are separate scripts handling learning/prediction, then the `scaler` will also need to be *serialized and loaded at prediction time*.

Set up a classification problem:

```py
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=10_000)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y)
```

Fit a `StandardScaler` instance on the training set and use the same parameters to `.transform` the test set:

```py
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)

# Train time: Serialize the scaler to a pickle file.
with open("scaler.pkl", "wb") as fh:
    pickle.dump(scaler, fh)

# Test time: Load the scaler and apply to the test set.
with open("scaler.pkl", "rb") as fh:
    new_scaler = pickle.load(fh)

X_test = new_scaler.transform(X_test)
```

Which means that the model should be fit on features with similar distributions:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.Input(shape=X_train.shape[1]),
    layers.Dense(100),
    layers.Dropout(0.1),
    layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")])
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["binary_accuracy"])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=25)

y_pred = np.where(model.predict(X_test)[:, 0] > 0.5, 1, 0)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
# 0.8708
```

Comment: The training part of the model was working (getting accuracy scores as expected)...its the live predict part with scaling that seems to fail..the above raises the same issue

Comment: I cannot see your live predict step, but like I said: you will need to serialize the `scaler` instance and load it in with the model at prediction time.

Comment: Its the first bit..the question is how to apply the same scaling when predicting, I am having to reshape etc.. I feel its missing something. For example when building the dataframe is passed but when predicting only an scaled array is passed. I feel either the feature selection should be done after scaling (with MinMaxScaler) or I am doing something wrong when reshaping etc

Comment: Added some extra code

Comment: I've adjusted the `StandardScaler` step in this answer, showing how to serialize it to disk and load it in at test time. I re-read the "feature selection" part but I do not understand it. As a debug step: check the dimensions (e.g. `X_train.shape`) are during training and make sure they are compatible at test time.

Comment: Added the error if I use "transform", the issue is not the training/testing, but at actually using it. The shape is correct (thus all that reshaping). Regarding feature selection, the features are not always the same --I use both SelectKBest (10 or 15 features) or RFECV (https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-with-real-and-categorical-data). And select the trained model with highest accuracy, meaning the features can be different every new model (the model gets retrained daily). I select the features first then scale in my code.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I improved the description of the problem

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer is correct, I think there is just some confusion between testing and live prediction. What he said regarding the testing step is equally applicable to live prediction step. After you've called `scaler.fit_transform` on your training set, add the following code to save the scaler:

```python
with open("scaler.pkl", "wb") as fh:
    pickle.dump(scaler, fh)
```

Then, during live prediction step, you don't call `fit_transform`. Instead, you load the scaler saved during training and call `transform`:

```python
with open("scaler.pkl", "rb") as fh:
    new_scaler = pickle.load(fh)

# Load features, reshape them, etc

# Scaling step
current_list = new_scaler.transform(current_list)

# Features are scaled properly now, put the rest of your prediction code here
```

You always call `fit_transform` only once per model, during the training step on your training pool. After that (during testing or calculating predictions after model deployment) you never call it, only call `transform`. Treat scaler as part of the model. Naturally, you fit the model on the training set and then during testing and live prediction you use the same model, never refitting it. The same should be true for the scaler.

If you call `scaler.fit_transform` on live prediction features it creates a new scaler that has no prior knowledge of feature distribution on training set.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the error: This MinMaxScaler instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator. When trying to predict live using "transform"

Comment: Also I am not using pickle for the keras model (when I use pickle for sklearn, the model works) but I use the "keras.models.load_model" function, maybe it has something to do with the issue?

Comment: The problem is not with the model serialisation, it's with the scaler serialisation. Either you serialise scaler before you fit it, or you don't deserialise it on prediction step and instead create an empty scaler by running something like `scaler = MinMaxScaler()`

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! Will test it out later today